# Print out .json line by line rather than all inside of one line

Tags: python, json

Creating a script that will eventually allow users to enter a hardware/asset id and query an API to get back a bunch of information, currently in the process of simply printing out the entire JSON file and printing it, however it currently prints it all to one line and makes it near impossible to read, ideally it looks like the following:

```
name: x
owner: x
team: x
```

and so on and so forth however it prints

`name: x owner: x team: x`

Code is as follows:

```
import json
from json import dumps, loads

def json_format():
    json.dumps(skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, default=None, sort_keys=False)

def main():
    hardware_id = "x"
    asset_id = "x"
    host = get_information(asset_id='x')
    json_object = dumps(host)
    print(dumps(json_object, indent=4))
```

Tried following some pretty print guides however the above didn't fix the issue I'm facing, any ideas thank you! :D

Comment: You are doing the JSON encoding twice.  The second one is just encoding the string value you already created.  Delete the `json_object = dumps(host)` line, and pass `host` in your `print` call.

Comment: Wow, lol - Thanks @TimRoberts life saver it worked!